# How to enforce Google Colab to utilise the GPU (using an external package to make sure GPU is used)?

Tags: gpu, runtime, google-colaboratory, cpu

So I am using Google Colab because I have some functions I need to execute that take far too long on my cpu. I have set the runtime to the GPU accelrator, however when I run the cell, I still get this message: 'Warning: You are connected to a GPU runtime, but not utilizing the GPU'.

I understand that this means the code I am running is just using my cpu. However using my cpu, the function takes hours to execute. This is why I want to utilise Colab's GPU, however, even when I change runtime, it still uses my cpu... How do I specifically force Colab to utilise the GPU for executing a certain cell/function in Colab???

Edit: I have just found out apparently Colab uses GPU only when the package being used is a package specifically made for GPU usage. Is there some sort of external package I can use that forces a function to find a GPU to use before executing the function?

Edit: (The package I am using for the long calculation is Network X if that makes any difference)

Answer (score 0):

Check out cuGraph, which lets you do the same graph calculations on the gpu as networkx. A [medium post](https://medium.com/rapids-ai/rapids-cugraph-networkx-compatibility-d119e417557c) on compatibility between cuGraph and networkx graphs.

You only need to do a couple of things to get cuGraph working on Google Colab. As the Google Colab demo from [this](https://medium.com/rapids-ai/run-rapids-on-google-colab-for-free-1617ac6323a8) medium post suggests:

- Use pynvml to confirm Colab allocated you a Tesla T4 GPU.
- Install most recent Miniconda release compatible with Google Colab's Python install (3.6.7)
- Install RAPIDS libraries
- Copy RAPIDS .so files into current working directory, a workaround for conda/colab interactions
- Update env variables so Python can find and use RAPIDS artifacts

---

```
!wget -nc https://github.com/rapidsai/notebooks- 
extended/raw/master/utils/rapids-colab.sh
!bash rapids-colab.sh

import sys, os

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/')
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_NVVM'] = '/usr/local/cuda/nvvm/lib64/libnvvm.so'
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_LIBDEVICE'] = '/usr/local/cuda/nvvm/libdevice/'
```

And then you can do the same calculations on the gpu:

```
pagerank = cugraph.pagerank(G)
```

instead of

```
pagerank = nx.pagerank(G)
```